# How to get number of images using driver Imagick on laravel 5

Tags: laravel, imagick

I used to get number of images from a file (.tiff or .tif) using Imagick

```
$document = new Imagick();
$document->readImage($path);
$pages = $document->getNumberImages();
```

Now that I use laravel to do my projects I am not being able to use the same method in the controller. I had to install the driver intervention Image and changed the driver to imagick.
Anybody knows what should be the command to get the number of images?
I have been looking everywhere and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getCore](http://image.intervention.io/api/getCore) function will let you access the underlying Imagick/GD instance.

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$imagick = $img->getCore();
$imagick->getNumberImages();
```

Comment: It almost works fine, but for some reason it is giving me number of images = 1 when there are 40 images in file. Do you know why it is doing that?

Comment: @JCD Nope. I'd note that you **can** use Imagick directly in Laravel's controllers, if you want.

Comment: Can you? when I try to use imagick directly in controller, it says this `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Imagick' not found`

Comment: You're really going to want to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php if you're working in Laravel. Add a \ before it (i.e. `$document = new \Imagick();`) or add a `use Imagick;` statement at the top of your controller (outside the class definition). You'll see this used heavily in Laravel.

Comment: Oh it works now. I added the \ before Imagick() before, and it didn't work; but that's because at that moment I didn't have imagick enabled/installed yet. Oooops... Thanks a  lot man! I will still try to figure out why it gave me 1 with the other method. Thanks again !